# Proper use of cudaFortran cuSolver functions

Tags: cuda, fortran, cusolver

I am currently working on migrating some Fortran code over to cudaFortran. Specifically the task involves the spectral analysis of massive matrices in order to diagonalize them. Here's the code I've fabricobbled so far

```
program main
!Trials for usage of cusovlerDn<t>syevd for spectral analysis of a symmetric matrix, see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#syevd-example1 for the example used as a base
!Compilation example: 'pgf90  Main.cuf -lcusolver -Mcuda=cuda8.0'
use cudafor !has to go first
use cusolverDn
    implicit none
integer :: info
    integer,parameter :: q2 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,305)
    real(q2), device, dimension(3,3) :: A_d
    real(q2), dimension(3,3) :: A
    real(q2), device, dimension(3) :: W_d
    real(q2), dimension(3) :: W
    integer :: stat, lwork, m, lda
    real(q2), device, allocatable  :: work_d(:)
    integer, device :: devInfo
    type(cusolverDnHandle) :: h
    stat=cusolverDnCreate(h)
        W_d=(/0,0,0/)
print *, stat
    m=3
    lda = m
    A_d(1,1:3)=(/4,1,2/)
    A_d(2,1:3)=(/1,-1,1/)
    A_d(3,1:3)=(/2,1,3/)    !eigenvalues are 5.84947, 1.44865, -1.29812
!   A_d(1,1:3)=(/1,0,0/)
!   A_d(2,1:3)=(/0,1,0/)
!   A_d(3,1:3)=(/0,0,1/)
    stat=cusolverDnDsyevd_bufferSize(h, CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, m,  A_d, lda, W_d, lwork)
print *, stat
    allocate(work_d(lwork))
    stat=cusolverDnDsyevd(h, CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, m, A_d, lda, W_d, work_d, lwork, devInfo)
print *, stat !returns 6 as if there was an error
info=devInfo
print *, info !devInfo returns 0, as if the operation was successful
    stat=cudaDeviceSynchronize()
print *, stat
    W=W_d
    print *, W
    A=A_d
    print *, A
    deallocate(work_d)
    stat=cusolverDnDestroy(h)
print *, stat
end program main
```

Compilation and mem-check output are as follows:

```
olafur@olafur-X556UQK:~/Skyrmions2017/Project$ pgf90  Main.cuf -lcusolver -Mcuda=cuda8.0
olafur@olafur-X556UQK:~/Skyrmions2017/Project$ cuda-memcheck ./a.out
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
            0
            0
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidDeviceFunction (error 8) due to "invalid device function" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef503]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x5b906e]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e0857]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e0270]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e3df3]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e1720]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e0157]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 (cusolverDnDsytrd + 0x37) [0x2e3f17]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2ea607]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2eb744]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 (cusolverDnDsyevd + 0x27) [0x2ea157]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x1b2d]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x1514]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf0) [0x20830]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x13f9]
=========
            6
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidDeviceFunction (error 8) due to "invalid device function" on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef503]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x5b6793]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e1727]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2e0157]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 (cusolverDnDsytrd + 0x37) [0x2e3f17]
            0
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2ea607]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 [0x2eb744]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0 (cusolverDnDsyevd + 0x27) [0x2ea157]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x1b2d]
            0
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x1514]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf0) [0x20830]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x13f9]
=========
    0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000         0.000000000000000     
    4.000000000000000         1.000000000000000         2.000000000000000      
    1.000000000000000        -1.000000000000000         1.000000000000000      
    2.000000000000000         1.000000000000000         3.000000000000000     
            0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
```

It looks like I'm not actually invoking the `cusolverDnDsyevd` functions properly, most likely I am not using the right types of variables. But since I am semi-illiterate in programming and the only example I have to follow is written in C (using those fancy void** things) I don't know what is proper.

EDIT: Full output of `deviceQuery`

```
olafur@olafur-X556UQK:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce 940MX"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2002 MBytes (2099642368 bytes)
  ( 3) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1242 MHz (1.24 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              64-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1048576 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce 940MX
Result = PASS
```

Comment: these switches: `-lcusolver -Mcuda=cuda8.0 -ms_50` don't belong on the `cuda-memcheck` command, but I don't believe they are hurting anything.  What GPU are you attempting to run this code on?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yep, got options and switches mixed up, the output is identical without the switches. Also, the ms-50 is just plain hogwash, I have changed the question accordingly. I am running this on my laptop's Geforce940MX but am hoping to run it on a nice Tesla K80 later. I have run various basic stuff sucessfully, cuBLAS and moving memory between CPU and GPU so I think it's properly set up.

Comment: When I compile your code with PGI 17.5 tools on linux and run with a Tesla P100, I get correct output with no errors reported by `cuda-memcheck`.   Here are the 3 eigenvalues reported: `-1.298117179004938         1.448645604364364         5.849471574640574` There may be a problem with the CUDA setup on your notebook.  What compute capability is reported by `deviceQuery` when run on your notebook?

Comment: I've added the full `deviceQuery` output in the question, I don't trust myself to parse it meaningfully for you.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas.  I think the code is correct, but there is obviously some runtime issue when running it on that particular device, which I don't have to test.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help. Do you have some suggestion for a simple turn on/off procedure I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code works fine on another system at my disposal the problem was indeed a runtime environment issue, as suggested by Robert Crovella

Moral of the story: Always try at least 2 systems.